# In PostgreSQL 10, why is a foreign key violation error not caught by pgplsql exception handling for deferrable constraints?

Tags: postgresql, exception, foreign-keys, plpgsql, deferrable-constraint

When calling a SQL function that performs an insert, from a PGPLSQL function with an EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS block, the exception is raised rather than caught if the violated foreign key constraint is deferrable.

I'm using Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL compatible (v 10.4).  I found that my exception handler wasn't always catching exceptions, which were instead being raised to the application (in my case an AWS Lambda Python function using Pyscopg2).

Took a lot of troubleshooting to narrow it down to the deferrable constraint, so I created a test function that reproduces the problem pretty reliably.

I've also reproduced the same behaviour on an RDS (non-Aurora) instance running version 10.5, and also on a 9.6.6 RDS instance so it's not Aurora and it's not specific to version 10.4.

Is this a bug?  Or am I missing something that's documented with deferrable constraints?

Here are two tables and two functions.

```
CREATE TABLE public.load (
  load_id           BIGINT                                 NOT NULL,
  created_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  ds_code           TEXT                                   NOT NULL,
  route             TEXT,
  file_name         TEXT,
  user_name         TEXT,
  staged            BOOLEAN,
  staging_duration  INTERVAL,
  CONSTRAINT load_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (load_id));


CREATE TABLE load_content (
  load_id           BIGINT NOT NULL,
  load_content      TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT data_load_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (load_id),
  CONSTRAINT data_load_load_load_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (load_id) REFERENCES public.load
)
;
CREATE FUNCTION insert_something() RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
INSERT INTO public.load_content values (1);

$$
;
CREATE FUNCTION test_load() RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$

BEGIN

  PERFORM public.insert_something();
  RETURN 'success';


  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 'failure';

END
  ;
$$
;
```

Executing public.test_load() returns a single row 'failure'.

If you then do this:

```
alter table public.load_content
  drop constraint data_load_load_load_id_fk;

ALTER TABLE public.load_content
  ADD CONSTRAINT data_load_load_load_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (load_id) REFERENCES public.load
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
;
```

Then execute public.test_load() the exception just happens:

```
[2019-01-14 16:36:32] [23503] ERROR: insert or update on table "load_content" violates foreign key constraint "data_load_load_load_id_fk"
[2019-01-14 16:36:32] Detail: Key (load_id)=(1) is not present in table "load".
```

Obviously, I've simplified this considerably for test purposes - what's actually happening in my system is a trigger on the "load" table that fires to normalise raw data (usually JSON) into a staging data model.

Comment: Checking a deferred constraint is postponed until the end of the transaction. In that case the function does not raise an exception because the checking is done after the function terminates.

Comment: @klin, so essentially you can't catch deferred FK violations at all?

Comment: @enjayaitch You can force imediate checks within the current transaction by using `SET CONSTRAINTS` statement. Going to post an answer with an example.

Comment: @enjayaitch - this could be possible only with transaction control inside a function. This functionality is available in procedures in Postgres 11. But then deferring a constraint makes a little sense I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DEFERRED` constraint check is postponed to the commit, an `IMMEDIATE` constraint check is executed as the name says, immediatly.
The behaviour of a `DEFERRABLE` constraint can be changed within the current transaction with the `SET CONSTRAINTS { ALL | name [, ...] } { DEFERRED | IMMEDIATE }` [(link to docs)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-set-constraints.html).

Should you want to change the behaviour of the `test_load()` function, here is the code example.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_load() RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$

BEGIN

  SET CONSTRAINTS data_load_load_load_id_fk IMMEDIATE;
  PERFORM public.insert_something();
  RETURN 'success';


  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 'failure';

END
  ;
$$
;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I guess it's logical that the commit happens after exception handling, but roll on V11 on Aurora...  I'm going to have to re-write my code to use data modifying CTEs in a monolithic statement to avoid the need for the deferrable constraints.  May be faster anyway so probably worth it.